# Paymill: do I need to create transactions for a subscription?

Tags: paymill

[Paymill](https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/): If I have created a subscription, will Paymill automatically create future transactions for me or do I have to manually create a transaction next month?

If it's automatic, how do I determine whether the transaction was successful or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paymill automatically creates a transaction for each subscription/offer after the defined period of time (week/month/year).  Each of these transactions has the subscription id in its description field so you can find them.  The status of those transactions is indicating whether the transaction was successful or not.